# Calling scanf function while in library

Tags: c, scanf, header-files

I´ve been having trouble using the scanf function while calling it from a .h file.

*mylib.h*

```
intnums() //Entering 2 numbers
    {
        textcolor(WHITE);
        printf("\nIntroduza dois números para realizar a operação selecionada.\n");
        scanf("%i%i",&a,&b);
    }
```

*sumsub.h*

```
sum(int a, int b) //Operation using previous introduction
{
    textcolor(WHITE);
    printf("\nA soma é: %i\n",a+b);
}
```

*main.c*

```
case 1:
    linha();
    intnums();
    sum(int b, int c);
    delay4sec();
    clear();
    break; 


//intnums calls for the function of entering the numbers and sum uses the entered numbers in intnums to calculate.
```

I´m new to coding and I still don´t understand much about it, and as such I´d like to ask for help in solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was the error you  received?

Comment: Please pass pointers to a and b to your intnums - that is a more structured way than placing the function into header file.

Comment: If you really want to put your function into .h, include that .h AFTER you declare `a` and `b` in `main.c`. But that is really wrong way to do it,

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `extern` keyword to share variable between files

*mylib.h*

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern a,b;
intnums() //Entering 2 numbers
    {
        textcolor(WHITE);
        printf("\nIntroduza dois números para realizar a operação selecionada.\n");
        scanf("%i%i",&a,&b);
    }
```

*sumsub.h*

```
sum(int a, int b) //Operation using previous introduction
{
    textcolor(WHITE);
    printf("\nA soma é: %i\n",a+b);
}
```

*main.c*

```
case 1:
    linha();
    intnums();
    sum(a,b);// you don,t have to use data type to pass the variable a&b are extern which are read by mylib.h
    delay4sec();
    clear();
    break;
```